# Am I allowed to break up $\ln^3x$ as $\ln x^2\ln x$ in order to solve a Integral (by parts)?

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

When I solve $\int \sec x^3\,dx$ by parts I can do $u=\sec x$, $du=\sec x\tan x\,dx$, $v=\tan x$ and $dv=\sec^2x$ and solve this way: $$\int \sec^2x\sec x=\sec x\tan x-\int \tan^2x\sec \tan x$$
When I take these I get the right answer. However, if I try something similar for $\ln^3x$ it does not work. I only get the right answer if I choose $u=\ln^3x$ and $v=x$. What am I missing?

Comment: Sometimes the technique just doesn't give anything useful.

Comment: You should better describe the steps you took to make us analyze them and find errors, if any.

Comment: well it depends if you mean $\ln^2 x\ln x$ or $\ln (x^2)\ln x$ one is ok, the other is not.

Comment: A $\LaTeX$ hint:  if you put backslashes before functions you get the proper font and spacing.  It works for all the trig functions you have here (though tangent needs to be tan, not tg).  You did it with $\ln$ in the title.

Comment: Allowed to, yes, as long as you write $\ln^3 x=\ln^2 x \ln x$  Maybe it is not useful, as you have found.

Comment: The answer is yes.  In fact, this approach is quite tractable - no more difficult than using $u=\log^3(x)$ and $v=x$.  I've posted a solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be the indefinite integral

$$I=\int \log^3(x)\,dx$$

We can indeed integrate by parts using $u=\log^2(x)$ and $v=x\log(x)-x$.  Proceeding, we find

$$\begin{align}
I&=x\log^3(x)-x\log^2(x)-2\int (\log^2(x)-\log(x))\,dx\\\\
&=x\log^3(x)-x\log^2(x)+2x\log(x)-2x-2\int \log^2(x)\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

We continue by integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, this time using $u=\log^2(x)$ and $v=x$.  We find that

$$\begin{align}
\int \log^2(x)\,dx&=x\log^2(x)-2\int \log(x)\,dx\\\\
&= x\log^2(x)-2x\log(x)+2x \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I=x\log^3(x)-3x\log^2(x)+6x\log(x)-6x+C}$$

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts, $$I_n=\int(\ln x)^n\ dx=(\ln x)^n\int\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(\ln x)^n}{dx}\int dx\right)dx$$

$$=x(\ln x)^n-n\int(\ln x)^{n-1}dx$$

$$\implies I_n=x(\ln x)^n-nI_{n-1}$$